# Inserting a variable with a comma in it to SQL database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I've been trying to insert a variable that has a comma in it to a SQL database for 30 minutes or so. I've echoed the variable, and the comma is there, but when it inserts, there's no comma!
Example (some code like mine):

```
$variable1 = "test";
$variable2 = "$variable1,";
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table (`column`) VALUES ('$variable2')";
$query1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1); //I dont think I need to put a con variable up there for an example code
```

And when I do:

```
echo $variable2;
```

The result is test, with the comma, but the data in the column is just test WITH NO COMMA.
Help please.
Thanks.

Edit:
Your Common Sense fixed it, apparently I needed brackets around '$variable2' so it's like:

```
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO table (`column`) VALUES (('$variable2'))";
```

Thanks Your Common Sense and everyone else who tried!

Comment: mysql isn't going to strip out a comma. Are you sure it's there when you do `var_dump($sql1)`? Does it show in the database when you do a `select * from table` in the mysql monitor or other db access tools?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the comma? It seems like it would work as-is, so this is a longshot, but maybe it is messing with your syntax

Comment: Could it just be that it gets truncated?

Comment: If you would bind the parameter instead of "injecting" it - you wouldn't be facing this problem (and also you wouldn't be vulnerable to sql-injection).

Comment: You should really look into prepared statements or PDO. This can be potentially dangerous. It is not difficult to use them and it makes your application safer.

Comment: As alfasin, I suspect there's some kind of injection prevention going on...

Comment: It's there when I do var_dump, not there when I do SELECT * FROM table, though. You mean to mysqli_real_escape_string it? I tried that and it's not working. How am I supposed to bind it? Please explain. I actually like PDO, please tel me how it can be dangerous?

Comment: How about the validity of `char`s in the DB dumper(?)?

Comment: what is the field type?

Comment: @user2917204 If you change the symbol will it stay the same? Instead of a comma add a dot.

Comment: Wait, I think the problem is that it's varchar, give me a minute. Edti: I don't really think it is.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks I added a dot, and same thing happens, doesn't show. I removed the bind param, though.

Comment: And if you run in the database console? Does it happen then?

Comment: When I run the query in the database console it inserts with the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer is simple.

It's **your own code** does remove this comma, either before insert or after fetch.
If you care to write a reproduceable test case, you will see that noone is taking your comma.

Test case means code that involves the behavior in question and **nothing else**. Not a single line of code beside insert and fetch:

```
$variable1 = "test";
$variable2 = "$variable1,";
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ('$variable2')";
mysqli_query($db,$sql1);

$sql2 = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='$variable2'";
$res  = mysqli_query($db,$sql2);
$row  = mysqli_fetch_row($res); 
var_dump($variable1, $variable2, $sql1, $sql2, $row[0]);
```

run it, see it all with comma in place, and then search your own code for the comma trimming code

or may be you have just test without comma in your table, ans select this one all the time, instead of one with comma.

or whatever silly error of the like

Comment: OH MY GOD! Apparently the brackets fixed it! I'm surprised I didn't try them before or that no one mentioned them. Thanks very much! What a stupid mistake!

Comment: @user2917204 what brackets you are talking about?

Comment: @EdgarKlerks see - it's even more *curiouser* now. Human error. An offtopic for this site.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The ones around '$variable2' in the query.

Comment: @user2917204 You need only ONE pair of brackets. And you had one in your query already. While without a pair of brackets you would be just unable to insert. what you really need is a good deal of sleep.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have completely lost it haha.

Comment: I had brackets, to tell the script the values, though, not around the variable. Oh well, that fixed it, that's PHP, gotta deal with it. :P

Comment: @user2917204 brackets around variable means NOTHING. You are either deeply confusing something or cheating.

Comment: Yea, I was deeply confused, haha, I gave the if statements the wrong queries, that was the error. :$

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table ('column') VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param($variable2);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

This is more safe and will not trigger such strangeties. (Is that a word?)

What happens here is, that the query is send to the sql database and this returns a statement. The statement has some holes, these are the ?, in it. 
When using bind_param you fill the holes and then you can execute.

This has a couple of advantages:

- It is safe
- You can reuse your statement
- It is easier than string interpolation stuff

Comment: Although its indeed more safe, but safety is not a question here. While regular method used by the OP will not trigger such strangeness as well.

Comment: That's true, but while it is interesting that he has some strange failure, we need the whole PHP configuration and version to find out why it happens. This is correct way, which will just work and walks around the whole problem.

Comment: Although if you can try this and it still happens then we can conclude it is something at the database level.

Comment: No, but this is still mysqli. PDO is not needed. [mysqli](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Gonna bind parm it though, give me a second.

Comment: What, I beg my pardon, you need PHP version for?

Comment: To reproduce it. Some PHP versions have strange quirks.

Comment: Do you have ANY CERTAIN "quirks" in mind? If not - what's the point in asking? Of course, no PHP version have such a "quirk" just because the OP is the first person ever with such a problem.

Comment: Wait, I think I've bind param'd it wrongly. Give me a minute or two.

Comment: @YourCommonSense

What is the problem? I am just interested in the version. I don't know if this is the first person ever asking and you don't know either. 

I know php does a lot of filtering and strange things behind the curtains in certain versions. So if I know the version I can compile it, install his version of mysql and see what happens, because I find the problem interesting.

Comment: Whatever. But if you don't know an answer, you have to express your fantasies in *comments* under the question.

Comment: Nope, I've done it right, no errors in error_log. And still, same problem, no comma. Ugh..

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ah ok, now I understand, that failed. Next time better then :)

Comment: Cheers. Sorry for being too strict. But really, this site suffers a lot from answers like this. I'd had no objections if they were rare, but in fact they are prevail. Just take an advise: if you see something unusual - don't trust to the OP blindly. We all humans and human error is way more probable than such a weird behavior.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No problem, I understand my initial mistake now :)

Answer (score -2):

Try `"INSERT INTO table ('column') VALUES ('" . $variable2 . "');"`

Comment: It is inserted with OP's code all right. Your code is no different.

Comment: It is inserted, without the comma though.